# Two way communicating using pipe

Tags: c, pipe, fork, parent-child, wait

I have a small program to practice pipe and processes in C. There is a parent process and there're two child processes (child_a, child_b). There're two array of pointers (each pointer points to a struct (Rabbit)) and the parent sends one of them to child_a and the other to child_b (using pipes). I'm using 4 pipes for communicating: pipefd_a1 and pipefd_b1 for parent->child and the other 2 for the child->parent way. The child processes modify the elements then send them back to the parent. Then the parent writes something to the console. So it's working until the last child process read the last data from pipe and then the program hangs. It writes a number to the console (2034, 10987, etc.) and then hangs. How can I solve this problem and why does not return from the while loop? Didn't I close all the pipes before reading from it?

```
typedef struct Rabbit {
    char* name;
    char* district;
    unsigned part_count;
    unsigned eggs_count;
} Rabbit;    

int pipefd_a1[2], pipefd_a2[2];
int pipefd_b1[2], pipefd_b2[2];
pid_t child_a, child_b;

// Pipe error checking
...

Rabbit** rabbits_a = (Rabbit**)malloc(sizeof(Rabbit*) * size);
Rabbit** rabbits_b = (Rabbit**)malloc(sizeof(Rabbit*) * size);

// Setting the array values (with malloc calls ofc)
...
// count_a is the size of rabbits_a, count_b is the size of rabbits_b

for (unsigned i = 0; i < count_a; ++i) {
    Rabbit rabbit = {rabbits_a[i]->name, rabbits_a[i]->district, rabbits_a[i]->part_count, rabbits_a[i]->eggs_count};
    write(pipefd_a1[1], &rabbit, sizeof(Rabbit));
}
for (unsigned i = 0; i < count_b; ++i) {
    Rabbit rabbit = {rabbits_b[i]->name, rabbits_b[i]->district, rabbits_b[i]->part_count, rabbits_b[i]->eggs_count};
    write(pipefd_b1[1], &rabbit, sizeof(Rabbit));
}

child_a = fork();

if (child_a == 0) {    // Child A
    close(pipefd_a2[0]);
    close(pipefd_a1[1]);
    Rabbit* rabbits = (Rabbit*)malloc(sizeof(Rabbit) * size);
    Rabbit rabbit;
    unsigned count_rabbits = 0;
    while (read(pipefd_a1[0], &rabbit, sizeof(Rabbit))) {
        // Do something with rabbit
        rabbits[count_rabbits++] = rabbit;
    }
    close(pipefd_a1[0]);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < count_rabbits; ++i) {
        write(pipefd_a2[1], &rabbits[i], sizeof(Rabbit));
    }
    close(pipefd_a2[1]);
} else {
    child_b = fork();

    if (child_b == 0) {    // Child B
        close(pipefd_b2[0]);
        close(pipefd_b1[1]);
        Rabbit* rabbits = (Rabbit*)malloc(sizeof(Rabbit) * size);
        Rabbit rabbit;
        unsigned count_rabbits = 0;
        while (read(pipefd_b1[0], &rabbit, sizeof(Rabbit))) {
            // Do something with rabbit
            rabbits[count_rabbits++] = rabbit;
        }
        // The execution does not reach this point
        close(pipefd_b1[0]);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < count_rabbits; ++i) {
            write(pipefd_b2[1], &rabbits[i], sizeof(Rabbit));
        }
        close(pipefd_b2[1]);
    } else {    // Parent
        pid_t pids[] = {child_a, child_b};
        pid_t returned_pid;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            struct stat dummy;
            char buf[70];
            sprintf(buf, "ps -e | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep %d", pids[i]);
            int result = system(buf);
            if (result != 0) {
                continue;
            }
            do {
                returned_pid = wait(NULL);
            } while (returned_pid != pids[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Complete code would be useful.  What is the relationship between `size` and `count_a`?

Comment: As we do not know the definition of `Rabbit`, this is not a [mre]. And without a [mre] we cannot guess the cause of your errors...

Comment: After you `malloc` space for `rabbits_a`, the memory `rabbits_a` points to is uninitialized.  Yet you attempt to read `rabbits_a[i]->name` right away, which is undefined behavior.  Further speculation is pointless.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I edited the question. There's no problem with memory allocating it is handled in another function which I didn't post here because I think it's irrelevant. The problem is that the execution doesn't reach the point which I commented in the code. So it means the program doesn't return from the while loop (which read from pipe)

Comment: Make sure you close the B pipes in child A, and the A pipes in child B.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: The parent process needs to close the  ends of the pipes that it doesn't use too.  If you don't close the pipes correctly, then the reading process doesn't get EOF and hangs, waiting for input that will never come.

Comment: After you writing to the pipes and then spawning the children to read the pipes?  A pipe can only buffer a small amount of data and will block the writer if it gets full.  If the writer gets blocked, it won't be able to spawn the children to read the pipes and will deadlock.  You probably don't want to write pointers into a pipe either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you demonstrate it in the code I posted please? I'm a beginner in this world of processes and I don't know what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my edit of your code.  I've reorganized the sequence of operations so that the child processes cannot 'cheat' by having the information that the parent is supposed to send to the children already available.  This code compiles; I've not run it because I'm not good at breeding rabbits and your code is incomplete at the point where the rabbit information should be created.

Note the plethora of `close()` calls.  Each child needs to close all four pipe descriptors for the other child, as well as the two it won't use.  The parent process must close eight pipe descriptors.  I've rewritten the wait processing — I don't think what you had is appropriate.  All else apart, if the 'wrong' child died first, you'd have problems. And running `ps | awk | grep` is not good — use `awk` alone or `grep` alone but not both.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct Rabbit
{
    char *name;
    char *district;
    unsigned part_count;
    unsigned eggs_count;
} Rabbit;

int main(void)
{
    int pipefd_a1[2], pipefd_a2[2];
    int pipefd_b1[2], pipefd_b2[2];
    pid_t child_a, child_b;

    if (pipe(pipefd_a1) != 0 ||
        pipe(pipefd_a2) != 0 ||
        pipe(pipefd_b1) != 0 ||
        pipe(pipefd_b2) != 0)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t size = 20;
    Rabbit **rabbits_a = (Rabbit **)malloc(sizeof(Rabbit *) * size);
    Rabbit **rabbits_b = (Rabbit **)malloc(sizeof(Rabbit *) * size);

    unsigned count_a = 10;
    unsigned count_b = 8;

    if ((child_a = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (child_a == 0)  // Child A
    {
        /* Not using b1 or b2 pipes at all */
        close(pipefd_b1[0]);
        close(pipefd_b1[1]);
        close(pipefd_b2[0]);
        close(pipefd_b2[1]);

        close(pipefd_a1[1]);
        close(pipefd_a2[0]);

        Rabbit *rabbits = (Rabbit *)malloc(sizeof(Rabbit) * size);
        Rabbit rabbit;
        unsigned count_rabbits = 0;
        while (read(pipefd_a1[0], &rabbit, sizeof(Rabbit)))
        {
            // Do something with rabbit
            rabbits[count_rabbits++] = rabbit;
        }
        close(pipefd_a1[0]);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < count_rabbits; ++i)
        {
            write(pipefd_a2[1], &rabbits[i], sizeof(Rabbit));
        }
        close(pipefd_a2[1]);
    }
    else if ((child_b = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (child_b == 0)
    {
        /* Not using a1 or a2 pipes at all */
        close(pipefd_a1[0]);
        close(pipefd_a1[1]);
        close(pipefd_a2[0]);
        close(pipefd_a2[1]);

        close(pipefd_b1[1]);
        close(pipefd_b2[0]);
        Rabbit *rabbits = (Rabbit *)malloc(sizeof(Rabbit) * size);
        Rabbit rabbit;
        unsigned count_rabbits = 0;
        while (read(pipefd_b1[0], &rabbit, sizeof(Rabbit)))
        {
            rabbits[count_rabbits++] = rabbit;
        }
        close(pipefd_b1[0]);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < count_rabbits; ++i)
        {
            write(pipefd_b2[1], &rabbits[i], sizeof(Rabbit));
        }
        close(pipefd_b2[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < count_a; ++i)
        {
            Rabbit rabbit = {rabbits_a[i]->name, rabbits_a[i]->district, rabbits_a[i]->part_count, rabbits_a[i]->eggs_count};
            write(pipefd_a1[1], &rabbit, sizeof(Rabbit));
        }

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < count_b; ++i)
        {
            Rabbit rabbit = {rabbits_b[i]->name, rabbits_b[i]->district, rabbits_b[i]->part_count, rabbits_b[i]->eggs_count};
            write(pipefd_b1[1], &rabbit, sizeof(Rabbit));
        }

        /* Close pipes so child processes get EOF */
        close(pipefd_a1[0]);
        close(pipefd_a1[1]);
        close(pipefd_a2[0]);
        close(pipefd_a2[1]);
        close(pipefd_b1[0]);
        close(pipefd_b1[1]);
        close(pipefd_b2[0]);
        close(pipefd_b2[1]);

        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
            printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It solves my problem. And if I want to read the informations from the pipe that cildren sent back I have to do it after the while (wait) loop?

Comment: You don't normally wait for people to die before reading their messages.  You shouldn't do that with messages from child processes either.  All else apart, if the child needs to send more data than will fit in the pipe buffer, it will be blocked until the parent reads some of the data, but if the parent doesn't read anything until the child died, you have a deadlock.  You may have to work out which pipes have information to be read, but `select()` or `poll()` or O_NONBLOCK can help.

Comment: Also, make sure sure you don't close any pipes you want to read from.